# extract all Json key values

Tags: python, json

I'm not advanced with Python Json. I have these Json result:

```
{
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists",
    "items": [
        {
            "collaborative": false,
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
            "id": "53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
            "images": [],
            "name": "Wizzlers Big Playlist",
            "owner": {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler",
                "id": "wizzler",
                "type": "user",
                "uri": "spotify:user:wizzler"
            },
            "public": true,
            "snapshot_id": "bNLWdmhh+HDsbHzhckXeDC0uyKyg4FjPI/KEsKjAE526usnz2LxwgyBoMShVL+z+",
            "tracks": {
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c/tracks",
                "total": 30
            },
            "type": "playlist",
            "uri": "spotify:user:wizzler:playlist:53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c"
        },
        {
            "collaborative": false,
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzlersmate/playlists/1AVZz0mBuGbCEoNRQdYQju"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzlersmate/playlists/1AVZz0mBuGbCEoNRQdYQju",
            "id": "1AVZz0mBuGbCEoNRQdYQju",
            "images": [],
            "name": "Another Playlist",
            "owner": {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzlersmate"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzlersmate",
                "id": "wizzlersmate",
                "type": "user",
                "uri": "spotify:user:wizzlersmate"
            },
            "public": true,
            "snapshot_id": "Y0qg/IT5T02DKpw4uQKc/9RUrqQJ07hbTKyEeDRPOo9LU0g0icBrIXwVkHfQZ/aD",
            "tracks": {
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzlersmate/playlists/1AVZz0mBuGbCEoNRQdYQju/tracks",
                "total": 58
            },
            "type": "playlist",
            "uri": "spotify:user:wizzlersmate:playlist:1AVZz0mBuGbCEoNRQdYQju"
        }
    ],
    "limit": 9,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 9
}
```

Now I need to extract only the Playlist ids. How to do that?

Edit:

I get the Json Data from doing:

```
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'users/' + user_id + '/playlists', headers=headers)

r = r.json()
```

`print(r)` returning me the Json Data. When I try to `data = json.load(r)`
I get these error! `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: `playlist_ids = [item.get('id') for item in data.get('items')]`, being 'data' that JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, load the JSON file using the built in `json` library.

```py
import json
with open('path/to/json/file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then, use a list comprehension to get only the IDs.

```py
playlist_ids = [item['id'] for item in data['items']]
```

**Edit:** Or, if you've got your JSON parsed already, just use the list comprehension. Don't do `r = r.json()`, that will reset the request object to the data. Set it to some other variable, `data` is OK - `data = r.json()`

```py
playlist_ids = [item['id'] for item in data['items']]
```

**Edit 2:** If you only want it where the owner ID is `"wizzler"`, then add a if clause to the list comprehension.

```py
playlist_ids = [item['id'] for item in data['items'] if item['owner']['id'] == 'wizzler']
```

Comment: I cant do data = json.load(r) please see my edit

Comment: I thought you posted a comment asking me if there was a way to filter only where the Owner ID is `"wizzler"`, it seems to be deleted now? If you don't need that functionality, let me know, and I'll rollback my edit.